# Film based on CC BY-SA 3.0 content

Tags: licensing, creative-commons, online-piracy

If a film was based on text content under CC BY-SA 3.0 and released in theaters, would there be any way to stop people from ripping the film and uploading it to YouTube or similar content sharing sites? Also would that still be considered Piracy?

Comment: I doubt any commercial movie production studio would be silly enough to do such a thing.

Comment: This is just hypothetical to help me understand this license more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If work is licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://freedomdefined.org/Licenses/CC-BY-SA-3.0) and released in theatres it would not be legal for anyone to prevent you from ripping (or using a handycam or whatever) to get the film, and then redistribute on Youtube or anywhere else.

This particular license has the clause

> "The freedom to redistribute copies: Copies may be sold, swapped or
>   given away for free, as part of a larger work, a collection, or
>   independently. There must be no limit on the amount of information
>   that can be copied. **There must also not be any limit on who can copy
>   the information or on where the information can be copied.** "

To the extent you use this work in your own work, that is OK also -

> "The freedom to distribute derivative works: In order to give everyone
>   the ability to improve upon a work, the license must not limit the
>   freedom to distribute a modified version (or, for physical works, a
>   work somehow derived from the original), regardless of the intent and
>   purpose of such modifications. However, some restrictions may be
>   applied to protect these essential freedoms or the attribution of
>   authors. "

If software piracy is [defined](http://www.yourdictionary.com/software-piracy) as "Unauthorized copying of some purchased software. "  then there is no software piracy occurring.

Comment: would it be possible for the author of the original text to give permission to the author of the film to use a different license without changing the license of the original text?

Comment: Yes, dual licensing is not uncommon.